# Can't upgrade asciidoctor because of outputOptions

Tags: java, gradle, asciidoctor

Currently, I'm using Asciidoctor Gradle plugin to generate documentation for my project. It's added in that way:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "org.asciidoctor.convert" version "2.4.0"
}
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.convert
...
dependencies {
    ...
    asciidoctor "org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-pdf:1.5.0-alpha.15"
    asciidoctor "org.asciidoctor:asciidoctorj-diagram:1.5.4.1"
}
...
asciidoctorj {
    version = '1.5.8'
    noDefaultRepositories = true
}
asciidoctor {
    sourceDir file('src/docs/asciidoc')
    backends = ['html5', 'pdf']

    sources {
        include 'documentation.adoc'
    }

    outputDir = file('build/docs')

    attributes([
        'pdf-stylesdir': "pdfTheme",
        'pdf-style': 'custom',
        'source-highlighter': 'coderay',
        'imagesdir': 'images',
        'toc': 'left',
        'icons': 'font',
        'javaVersion': System.getProperty("java.version"),
        'currentDate': new Date().format("d. MMM yyyy"),
        'allow-uri-read': true
    ])

    // good to see what the build is doing...
    logDocuments = true

    requires = ['asciidoctor-diagram']
}

task asciidocToHTML (
        type: AsciidoctorTask,
        group: 'Document Generation',
        description: 'use html5 as asciidoc backend') {

    attributes([
        'plantUMLDir': ''
    ])

    backends = ['html5']
    mustRunAfter "openApiToAsciidoc"
}

task asciidocToPDF (
        type: AsciidoctorTask,
        group: 'Document Generation',
        description: 'use pdf as asciidoc backend') {

    attributes([
        'plantUMLDir': file("build/images/plantUML/").path
    ])

    backends = ['pdf']
    mustRunAfter "openApiToAsciidoc"
}

task openApiToAsciidoc (
        type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask,
        group: 'Document Generation',
        description: 'generate AsciiDoc from OpenApi specification') {

    generatorName = "asciidoc"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/specs/src/main/resources/openapi.json".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()

    configOptions = [
            headerAttributes: "false"
    ]

}
```

Now, everytime I run my gradle build it suggest me to upgrade that version because of deprecated features:

```
You are using one or more deprecated Asciidoctor Gradle plugin features.
These will be removed in 3.0 of these plugins.
To help you migrate we have compiled some tips for you based upon your current usage.
- Task: asciidoctor:
  - You have used 'backends'. When upgrading you will need to: Use outputOptions.setbackends
  - You have used 'requires'. When upgrading you will need to: When upgrading GEMs, 'requires' will need to be set via the asciidoctorj project and task docExtensions. Use  setGemPaths method in extension(s) to set GEM paths.
- org.asciidoctor.convert:
  - 'org.asciidoctor.convert' is deprecated. When you have time please switch over to 'org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert'.
  - jcenter() is no longer added by default. If you relied on this behaviour in the past, please add jcenter() to the repositories block.
```

However, I can't upgrade it because when I try to use

```
asciidoctor{ 
...
  outputOptions { 
    backends = ['html5'] 
  }
}
```

I got following error:

> Could not find method outputOptions() for arguments [build_bwu06l6l07d4ekv1kid7x1qa4$_run_closure16$_closure39@7254a9f3] on task ':asciidocToPDF' of type org.asciidoctor.gradle.AsciidoctorTask.

Also, when used org.asciidoctor.gradle.jvm.AsciidoctorTask got a following problem:

> Cannot cast object 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.compat.AsciidoctorExtension_Decorated@17a75298' with class 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.compat.AsciidoctorExtension_Decorated' to class 'org.ysb33r.grolifant.api.AbstractCombinedProjectTaskExtension'

Comment: which version of gradle are you using? Maybe https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-examples/tree/master/asciidoc-to-html-example might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
asciidoctor{ 
  ...
  outputOptions { 
    backends 'html5'
  }
}
```

instead.